# Auth0 integration and UI with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, auth0

I'm trying to use Auth0 for my mobile application (Xamarin) and I've been following the [quickstart guide provided by Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/xamarin).

I've installed the component via Xamarin market (Visual Studio) and to do the integration, I've created a class file dedicated to Auth0 related operations. I copied and pasted the provided code from the quick start guide but visual studio returns this error:

> The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code

The code provided used `var` instead of a normal variable so I'm not sure what I can substitute with it:

```
using Auth0.SDK;

namespace Application
{
    class LoginHandler
    {
        var auth0 = new Auth0Client(
        "*************",
        "************************");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'd also like some help implementing the Login UI as the Xamarin guides are deathly outdated.

Comment: poke poke poke poke

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: You can use `Auth0Client` instead of `var`.

```
internal class LoginHandler
{
    private Auth0Client auth0 = new Auth0Client("***", "*****");
}
```

**Long answer**:

The snippet is assuming you would use the Auth0 client instance in a context where it would be considered a local variable and as such it would be valid code. For example:

```
internal class LoginHandler
{
    public void HandleLogin()
    {
        var auth0 = new Auth0Client("***", "*****");
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

<sub>If you require assistance in solving other specific issues then you should post specific questions that clearly illustrate the problem you're having.</sub>